# Google API FAILED_PRECONDITION Precondition check failed

Tags: gmail-api

I'm currently facing a 400 error when calling Gmail API.

I have enabled Gmail API in my Google Cloud console (it is G Suite account, not personal account).

And i have created a service account, then try to use postman to test out the Gmail API.

I'm using my service account to exchange a Bearer Token

I have requested all the possible scopes.

[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata, https://mail.google.com/, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify]

And then I use the token to access the following endpoint.

GET **https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages**

It gives me the following error. I have been googling for a few days but i have no luck.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Precondition check failed.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Precondition check failed.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "failedPrecondition"
            }
        ],
        "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
    }
}
```

This is the my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream("/home/rl/.gsutil/prive-production-appDev.json"));

        credentials = credentials.createScoped(GmailScopes.all());

        System.out.println(credentials.getAuthenticationType());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxx"));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress("xxxx"));
        email.setSubject("test");
        email.setText("test");

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        email.writeTo(buffer);

        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(buffer.toByteArray());
        com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message message = new com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);

        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

        Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName("Prive Technologies")
                .build();

        ListMessagesResponse res = gmail.users().messages().list("me").execute();

        message = gmail.users().messages().send("me", message).execute();

    } catch (IOException | MessagingException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm using this :

Comment: Are you using the service acocunt in conjunction with impersonaiton? Please show your code to implement the service account.

Comment: I'm using google-api-services-gmail

Comment: i have pasted my code in the question.

Comment: This error *can* happen when the maximum number of keys already exists. (10 in my case.) The solution would then be to delete one of the existing keys.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out it might be access/service account permissions issue. It might not be right away clear to the end user, but following up with Google through support ticket turned out the account permissions were not sufficient. Fixing permissions allowed to proceed forward.