# GCP AI Platform (unified) Python export_model FailedPrecondition: 400 Exporting artifact in format `` is not supported

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-ai-platform

I am using the Google AiPlatform (Unified) Python client to export a trained model to a Google Cloud bucket. I am following the sample code from: [export_model_sample](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/master/samples/snippets/export_model_sample.py).

The application has "owner" credentials at the moment because I want to make sure it is not a permissions issue. However, when I try to execute the sample code I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
> return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in **call**
> return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
> raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
> grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
> status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
> details = "Exporting artifact for model `projects/101010101010/locations/us-central1/models/123123123123123` in format `` is not supported." debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1611864688.554145696","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.12.202:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Exporting artifact for model `projects/110101010101/locations/us-central1/models/123123123123123` in format `` is not supported.","grpc_status":9}"
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/app/main.py", line 667, in
>
> response = aiplatform_model_client.export_model(name=name, output_config=output_config)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/services/model_service/client.py",
> line 937, in export_model
> response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py",
> line 145, in **call**
> return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py",
> line 59, in error_remapped_callable
> six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)   File "", line 3, in raise_from
> google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 Exporting artifact
> for model
> `projects/111101010101/locations/us-central1/models/123123123123123123`
> in format `` is not supported.

(I have omitted the project id and the models id. Using 10101 and 123123)

I have verified my inputs but everything seems ok:

```
gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix = "gs://my-bucket-vcm/model-123123123123123/tflite/2021-01-28T16:00:00.000Z/"
gcs_destination = {"output_uri_prefix": gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix}
output_config = {"artifact_destination": gcs_destination,}
name = "projects/10101010101/locations/us-central1/models/123123123123123"
response = aiplatform_model_client.export_model(name=name, output_config=output_config)
print("Long running operation:", response.operation.name)
export_model_response = response.result(timeout=300)
print("export_model_response:", export_model_response)
```

I am also using the latest version of google-cloud-aiplatform==0.4.0
The model that I am trying to export is of type: MOBILE_TF_LOW_LATENCY_1

I would like to just export the model to a cloud bucket. Not deploy it as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [export_model_sample](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/master/samples/snippets/export_model_sample.py) is missing a request field. You should include `"export_format_id": string` in the `output_config`. You can further explore the required `output_config` fields required by [export endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/export#outputconfig) in the AI Platform Unified REST API Reference.

The accepted values for `export_format_id` are the following:

- `tflite` Used for Android mobile devices.
- `edgetpu-tflite` Used for Edge TPU devices.
- `tf-saved-model` A tensorflow model in SavedModel format.
- `tf-js` A TensorFlow.js model that can be used in the browser and in
  Node.js using JavaScript.
- `core-ml` Used for iOS mobile devices.
- `custom-trained` A Model that was uploaded or trained by custom code.

The code should look like this. In this case I used `tflite` for the `export_format_id`.

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

def export_model_sample(
    project: str = "your-project-id",
    model_id: str = "your-model-id",
    gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix: str = "your-bucket-destination",
    location: str = "us-central1",
    api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
    timeout: int = 300,
):
    # The AI Platform services require regional API endpoints.
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    # Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
    # This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    client = aiplatform.gapic.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    output_config = {
        "export_format_id": "tflite",
        "artifact_destination": {"output_uri_prefix": gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix}
    }
    name = client.model_path(project=project, location=location, model=model_id)
    response = client.export_model(name=name, output_config=output_config)
    print("Long running operation:", response.operation.name)
    export_model_response = response.result(timeout=timeout)
    print("export_model_response:", export_model_response)

export_model_sample()
```

I got a model named in this manner after the operation was completed:

> gs://your-bucket-destination/your-model-id/tflite/2021-01-29T04:15:51.672336Z/model.tflite

Comment: Correct. https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/issues/194

Comment: The last line is not printing anything for me: print("export_model_response:", export_model_response)

So I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/issues/197

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate one of my other answers [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520276/google-api-failed-precondition-precondition-check-failed/76783677#76783677), check access/service account permissions. Fixing those fixed the issue (not sure if my DevOps team or Google changed those in the meantime, but rechecking permissions solved it). Note: it will not be right away clear from the error message these are the missing permissions, but looking deeper under-the-hood on the Google side might yield such answer. They are supposed to make feature-request for a more verbose error reporting, but for the time being it is what it is.